enabling a view only calendar utilizing date picker in flet
I am planning to apply a calendar features on my app, and i want to utilize the view only part of the date picer from flet but when i try to do it, it failed
    def content(self):
        date_picker = ft.DatePicker(
            first_date=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=365),  
            last_date=datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=365),   
        )
        return ft.Column(controls=[
            self._time_container,
            date_picker
        ])

I have tried it in other file and it still fails unless i use a button.
